# Changing subitem background color c#

Tags: c#, listview, colors, background

I'm trying to change the background color of an especific column from my listview object, in C#.

I have just two columns: the first is called "Sequence" and the other one is called "Residue". The second one, called "Residue", is the column i want to "paint".

The code I'm using just change the full row background and not the column "Residue".

Hope anyone can help!

Thanks a lot.

Here is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Variables.NSeqSNP; i++)
        {
            char res = Variables.SequencesSNP[i].ToString()[pos];
            ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(Variables.SeqNameSNP[i].ToString());
            lvi.SubItems.Add(res + " ");
            if (res == 'A') lvi.SubItems[0].BackColor = Color.Blue;
            else if (res == 'T') lvi.SubItems[0].BackColor = Color.Red;
            else if (res == 'C') lvi.SubItems[0].BackColor = Color.Green;
            else if (res == 'G') lvi.SubItems[0].BackColor = Color.Yellow;

            lstOutputSNP.Items.Add(lvi);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to paint the second row, then you'll need to use SubItems[1]. As for painting, add "lvi.UseItemStyleForSubItems = false;" as seen below

```
for (int i = 0; i < Variables.NSeqSNP; i++)
{
    char res = Variables.SequencesSNP[i].ToString()[pos];
    ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(Variables.SeqNameSNP[i].ToString());
    lvi.SubItems.Add(res + " ");
    lvi.UseItemStyleForSubItems = false;
    if (res == 'A') lvi.SubItems[1].BackColor = Color.Blue;
    else if (res == 'T') lvi.SubItems[1].BackColor = Color.Red;
    else if (res == 'C') lvi.SubItems[1].BackColor = Color.Green;
    else if (res == 'G') lvi.SubItems[1].BackColor = Color.Yellow;

    lstOutputSNP.Items.Add(lvi);
}
```